# Woocommerce - How can I add custom message in a specific place to Order Completed email?

Tags: email, woocommerce

I am trying to add a custom message to the woocommerce Order Completed Email. I would like to add a this thank you note at the beginning of the email:
"Your feedback is very important to us in order to provide you with the best quality service. So don't forget to leave a comment about how well did we do."

I tried to edit PHP templates but with no good result.

[image: Place to put message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this code in functions.php file of your theme:

```
function action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table( $order, $int, $int ) { 
    if($order->get_status() == 'completed') {
       _e("Your custom text goes here"); 
    }
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 10, 3 );
```

It will also be translatable as a string.